# Using a Range within a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to remove certain text within assigned cells. All works great. Except, I am adding more cells that require this code. Is there a simpler way of not having to list each cell.

```vb
Sub Removetext()
    For Each c In Range("D18,D20,D22,D24,D26,D28,D30,D32,D34,D61,D63,D65,D67,D69,D71,D73,D75,D77,D79,D81,D83,D85")
        If InStr(c.Value, "{") > 0 Then
            c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, "{") - 1)
        End If
            If InStr(c.Value, "*") > 0 Then
            c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, "*") - 1)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

I've searched other post and could not find anything.

Comment: You could use a loop with `Step 2` to go over each range, but they appear to be different sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for each group of cells:

```vb
Sub Removetext()
    Dim rng As Range, addr, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, c As Range, v, v2
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each addr In Array("D18:D34", "D65:D85")
        Set rng = ws.Range(addr)
        For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count Step 2
            Set c = rng.Cells(i) 'set the cell
            v = c.Value          'read the value
            v2 = v               'store a copy of the value
            TrimLeft v, "{"
            TrimLeft v, "*"
            If v <> v2 Then c.Value = v 'replace if changes were made
        Next i
    Next addr
End Sub

'take the left part of a string up to `lookfor` (if present)
Sub TrimLeft(ByRef s, lookFor As String)
    Dim pos
    pos = InStr(s, lookFor)
    If pos > 0 Then s = Left(s, pos - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you much for your response. I tired running the code and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you first fill in the missing part?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the "missing part".

Comment: Edited above - now complete